# file downloading using php echo statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my project. I have 2 files named index.php and download.php, in which index.php is showing some contents dynamically from table, so I want to download the table  content like joe.pdf as I will click my link,but the code that i have written is showing some problem like invalid file,I think i missed something in that filedownloading echo statement

so I am enclosing the two files here:

**index.php**

```
<?php
    // Establish Connection with Database
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root");

    // Select Database
    mysql_select_db("cms", $con);

    // Specify the query to execute
    $sql = "select * from user_tbl where approval='0'";

    // Execute query
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);

    $i = 1;

    //echo "<form action='process.php' method='post'>"; 
    echo "<table border='.025'>
    <tr>
    <th>UID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Mobile</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>gender</th>
    <th>BirthDate</th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Password</th>
    <th>Station-Name</th>
    <th>Verification Proof</th>
    <th>Approve</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['User_Id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Address'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['City'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Mobile'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Gender'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['BirthDate'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['UserName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Password'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Station_Name'] . "</td>";
        //echo "<td>" . $row['VerificationProof'] . "</td>";
        $name=$row['VerificationProof'];enter code here
        echo "<td><a href='download.php?filename=$name'>$name</a></td>"; 
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='check[$i]' value='".$row['User_Id']."'/>";   
        echo "</tr>";
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
<br>
</br>
<?php 
    echo "<input type='submit' name='approve' value='approve'/>";
    echo "</form>";
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

**download.php**

```
<?php
    function output_file($file, $mime_type='') {
        if(!is_readable($file)) die('File not found or inaccessible!');

        $size = filesize($file);
        $name = rawurldecode($name);
        $known_mime_types=array(
            "pdf" => "application/pdf",
            "txt" => "text/plain",
            "html" => "text/html",
            "htm" => "text/html",
            "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
            "zip" => "application/zip",
            "doc" => "application/msword",
            "xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
            "ppt" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
            "gif" => "image/gif",
            "png" => "image/png",
            "jpeg"=> "image/jpg",
            "jpg" => "image/jpg",
            "php" => "text/plain"
        );
        if($mime_type=='') {
            $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));
            if(array_key_exists($file_extension, $known_mime_types)) {
                $mime_type=$known_mime_types[$file_extension];
            } else {
                $mime_type="app`enter code here`lication/force-download";
            };
        };

        @ob_end_clean();

        if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
            ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
        header('Content-Type: ' . $mime_type);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
        header("Cache-control: private");
        header('Pragma: private');
        header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
            list($a, $range) = explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'],2);
            list($range) = explode(",",$range,2);
            list($range, $range_end) = explode("-", $range);
            $range=intval($range);
            if(!$range_end) {
                $range_end=$size-1;
            } else {
                $range_end=intval($range_end);
            }
            $new_length = $range_end-$range+1;
            header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
            header("Content-Length: $new_length");
            header("Content-Range: bytes $range-$range_end/$size");
        } else {
            $new_length=$size;
            header("Content-Length: ".$size);
        }
        $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024);
        $bytes_send = 0;
        if ($file = fopen($file, 'r')) {
            if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
                fseek($file, $range);
            while(!feof($file) && (!connection_aborted()) && ($bytes_send<$new_length)) {
                $buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
                print($buffer);
                flush();
                $bytes_send += strlen($buffer);
            }
            fclose($file);
        } else
            die('Error - can not open file.');
        die();
    }
    set_time_limit(0);
    $file_path='Documents/'.$_REQUEST['filename'];
    output_file($file_path, ''.$_REQUEST['filename'].'', 'text/plain');
?>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: why you comment `//echo "<form action='process.php' method='post'>";`

Comment: You've got a lot of errors in your code. For example: `$name=$row['VerificationProof'];enter code here` <-- looks to be trailing information (maybe an old todo that needs to be removed). `<br><br />` is a self closing tag. This should be corrected to read `<br />`. You've got two `if` statements near the top of the second code block with trailing `;`. I don't think this would matter but it is definitely not consistent. You should review your code and correct the syntax and semantic errors before tackling this problem. It may even fix this problem.

Comment: You should either use anchor link to pass your request parameter from index.php to download.php or use form. You have form closing tag left in the code and the submit button is even unnecessary in this case.

Comment: sir i have a HTML statement like this

    <td >
    <a href="download.php?filename=<?php echo $name1;?>"><?php echo $name1 ;?></a>
    </td>

i want to convert it to the corresponding php statement using echo

i tried like follows
   
   echo "<td><a href='download.php?filename=$name1'>$name1</a></td>"; 


but something is missing so it is showing some errors,so plse help me



how can i convert an html statement i have given below to a php statement

Comment: may be if you can help me for this my code will work

Comment: Your function output_file() has two parameters in definition but function call has three parameters.

Comment: i converted it like this still also it is showing File not found or inaccessible!,,,,, i think error is in this statement,i missed smething in it...

Comment: echo "<td><a href='download.php?filename=$name'>$name</a></td>";

Comment: output function i changed like this function output_file($file, $name, $mime_type='')

Comment: try giving full path to $file_path variable